# How do I redirect back to the action that the action was called from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could pass in a params[:action_callback], but wondering if there is a more elegant way to approach this?

```
1) I called /submit_posting from the /network page
2) After submit_posting does their magic, i want to do a redirect back to /network
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`redirect_to :back`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464)